# How to align headings horizontally in two independent cols in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to do the following:

I have a Bootstrap layout with Descriptions of two employees.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      EMPLOYE1
      HEADING1
      HEADING2
      HEADING3
      ...
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      EMPLOYE2
      HEADING1
      HEADING2
      HEADING3
      ...
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**How do I...**

- Align Heading1 with Heading1, Heading2 with Heading2, ... **if the cols are beside each other**?
- Not care about the Heading alignment **if the cols are below each other**?

I have searched google/duckduckgo but it seems that there are too many alignment issues with alignment in html. Or maybe what I'm trying is just not possible?

Comment: we actually need more code to work with. I don't see a problem with the code sample you added.

Comment: The problem is, that the code above doesn't necessarily put HEADING1 in EMPLOYE1 next to HEADING1 in EMPLOYE2 (it puts it anywhere depending on the text before.)